# Solving a 2nd order non-linear ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, elliptic-functions, nonlinear-dynamics

First off, please correct me if my title is wrong.

I want to solve an equation which has the following form:

$f'' + Af^3 + Bf = 0$

The closest I have gotten to such a form was when looking as the Jacobi elliptic differential equations, but I am unsure of how to proceed.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

**Hint:**

$$f'f''+(Af^3+Bf)f'=0$$

and

$$\frac12f'^2+A\frac{f^4}4+B\frac{f^2}2+C=0.$$

This is a separable equation.

Comment: Hi. Thanks for your answer. After some work I arrived at your separable equation. However, proceeding to directly integrate I have arrived at an awkward place:

Assuming the derivative is wrt. $\theta$, I have

$\int \frac{1}{\sqrt{\frac{AF^4}{2} + BF^2 + 2C}}dF = i\theta$,

where I have moved the $i$ from the LHS.

Is there a clever way to tackle such an integral?

Comment: @AdamKoval: what do you mean by "after some work" ? It's all there. The clever way is using Alpha, the integral is painful.

Comment: I mean I had to directly integrate to arrive from your first to your second eqn..

Can you elaborate on what you mean by "using Alpha"?

Comment: $$(f^2)'=2ff',(f'^2)'=2f'f''$$ Wolfram Alpha.

Comment: I see. Thanks for your help :)